# Invalid appId Bing Translate (WP7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, reference, bing, translate

> ArgumentException: Invalid appId Parameter name: appId :
>   ID=3737.V2_Soap.Translate.30597BC0

I am getting the above error message everytime I try to run the translate service.

The error is pointing me to the below c# code for references.cs

```
public string EndTranslate(System.IAsyncResult result) {
                object[] _args = new object[0];
                string _result = ((string)(base.EndInvoke("Translate", _args, result)));
                return _result;
            }
```

I am using this on windows phone 7 and it had worked previously but now i am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is because of [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/microsofttranslator/thread/02054a7c-090c-46a0-a8d1-2d57e236eb4d/).

> Back in September 2011, we deprecated the use of Bing AppIDs for the
>   Translator service. In reality, existing and new AppIDs continued to
>   work until yesterday. We have now disabled the use of new Bing AppIDs:
>   requests using a Bing AppID that has not been used with the Translator
>   service before March 31, 2012 will be denied.
>
> Please upgrade to the secure method of Azure Marketplace tokens.

I have the same error, I am working now to obtain that new token from `Azure Translate`.